# Compare Images in Database

Tags: java, database, image

I get 25 sample pieces from an image, get their average rgb values and save them in 5x5 Color arrays. These are my "signatures". Values in signatures are like following:

```
Color signature[5][5];

-21233 -1 -323211 ... ...
-123 -12323 ...  
...
```

I can reach red, blue and green values from indexes of the signature. I use these values to compare two images' signatures and get a "difference" value.

```
signature[1][1].getBlue() = 123, Color[1][1].getRed() = 200 ..

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {   
        for (int y = 0;y < 5; y++) {
            int r1 = signature[x][y].getRed();
            int g1 = signature[x][y].getGreen();
            int b1 = signature[x][y].getBlue();
            int r2 = signature2[x][y].getRed();
            int g2 = signature2[x][y].getGreen();
            int b2 = signature2[x][y].getBlue();
            double tempDiff =  Math.sqrt((r1 - r2) * (r1 - r2) 
                                       + (g1 - g2) * (g1 - g2) 
                                       + (b1 - b2) * (b1 - b2));
            difference += tempDiff;
        }
 }
```

I also got a second signature for images, showing their edge-found version's signatures. Comparing two images, I multiply normal-signature difference with edge-signature difference and get the final difference value.

Everything works great in comparing two images. However, I got lots of images, so I saved my signatures in database like following:

```
Table images:
-COLUMN name-       -COLUMN signature-             -COLUMN edge signature-
myimg.jpg  |-12312 -132 -2 ... (25 of them) |-123 -1 -1234 -6921 .. (25 of them)|
```

I simply concatenate signature indexes with spaces between them and save as String.

Here's my question: I need to find similarities for one image. If I select all images from the database, things get really slow and I'm out of memory. I can select 1000's of images from database, compare and get the next 1000, but this is even slower.

I need a way to compare the image signatures in the query, I am ready to change my table's columns, even ready to try insane tables with 100 columns holding all RGB values of the signature. I need reducing or hashing of the signature. It there any ways/approaches, links or libraries can you suggest? Any help would be appreciated.

If needed, I use Java on NetBeans, working with MySQL.

Comment: *"Here's my question"*  This nothing in that paragraph, or following, that is a question.

Comment: Added a sentence with a question mark according to your quest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing that we need 150 columns, two approaches came into mind:

1. Reducing the number of columns according to a logic.
2. Using perceptual hash (hashing in which close hash values represent close before-hashed values)

However, after an ugly and messy implementation, the code worked just fine. What I'm doing is simply doing the calculation in the question with an SQL query and getting the most similar 50 pictures from the database. After I got the results I tidied up the code a little bit, and it's working fine and fast.

So we saw no real need to implement the approaches above as they reduce the success of finding similarities and we don't need to be faster. We get the best 50 results, so memory complexity isn't a problem, too.

For all those have speed or memory problems in "Java part" (or any other "code" part) in the project, I strongly recommend to transfer as much work as it can get to "Database part" and get the things done with queries.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing most probably won't work, because you are searching for similar, not identical images. It won't work even if you map similar images to the same key, since "similar" relation is not transitive based on your definition of comparison function (A similar to B, B similar to C, but C may not be similar to A).

The only thing I can think of is to store in 25 * 3 columns as you said. You can write the SQL statement to select only images that **may** pass the distance test (if the difference is already larger than the threshold, then filter it away). If the images in the DB are not too similar, this method should work OK. However, if the images in the DB closely resemble each other, this method is bad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need red, green and blue values separately to compare, so I need 25 colors x 3(r,g,b) x 2 (color,edge) = 150 columns. That's what I'm implementing now. By the way, the images aren't close to each other. Is there any suggestions that doesn't give away too much similarity success and reduce my column numbers?

Comment: Sorry. I have no experience in graphic processing so I can't help you on this.

Comment: The method works fast enough with 150 columns, the queries and the code got really ugly, but it's successful. So there's no real need to reduce column numbers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to do that.

If you want to find all duplicates you can use something like this (substitute proper field names)

```
SELECT i.[name] FROM images i 
  INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT signature, edge_signature 
          FROM images
           GROUP BY signature, edge_signature
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) dups
   on i.signature = dups.signature and i.edge_signature = dups.edge_signature;
```

If you want to find duplicates of a particular image, create the signatures and put them in this SQL

```
SELECT i.[name]
  FROM images
    WHERE signature = '$yourCalculatedSignaturehere'
    and edge_signature = '$yourCalculatedEdgeSignaturehere';
```

Both of these queries may return multiple rows (or 0 rows if there are no duplicates).

You might be able to speed these queries up using an index on `signature, edge_signature, [name]`
(this index might double the disk space used by your table, but it should significantly improve performance of the query).

Comment: I want to find similarities, not the duplicates.